# Unity - How can I use a flag to decide whether all the objects rotate at once or each one individually?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class SpinableObject
{
    [SerializeField]
    private Transform t;
    [SerializeField]
    private float rotationSpeed;
    [SerializeField]
    private float minSpeed;
    [SerializeField]
    private float maxSpeed;
    [SerializeField]
    private float speedRate;
    private bool slowDown;

    public void Rotate()
    {
        if (rotationSpeed > maxSpeed)
            slowDown = true;
        else if (rotationSpeed < minSpeed)
            slowDown = false;

        rotationSpeed = (slowDown) ? rotationSpeed - 0.1f : rotationSpeed + 0.1f;
        t.Rotate(Vector3.forward, Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);
    }
}
public class SpinObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    private bool slowDown = false;
    private GameObject[] allPropellers;
    public bool rotateAll = false;
    public float rotationSpeed;
    public float slowdownMax;
    public float slowdownMin;
    public SpinableObject[] objectsToRotate;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        allPropellers = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Propeller");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (rotateAll == false)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < objectsToRotate.Length; i++)
            {
                objectsToRotate[i].Rotate();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            objectsToRotate = new SpinableObject[allPropellers.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < allPropellers.Length; i++)
            {
                objectsToRotate[i].Rotate();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the else in this part I want that all the objects will rotate with the global variables settings. And if the rotateAll is false each one will rotate with their own options settings.

```
            objectsToRotate = new SpinableObject[allPropellers.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < allPropellers.Length; i++)
            {
                objectsToRotate[i].Rotate();
            }
```

But here I'm only make instance for more places in the objectsToRotate they are all null. And I'm not sure using objectsToRotate is good to rotate them all at once.

Update: This is what i tried now:

I changed the SpinableObject script to:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class SpinableObject
{
    public Transform t;
    public float rotationSpeed;
    public float minSpeed;
    public float maxSpeed;
    public float speedRate;
    public bool slowDown;
}
public class SpinObject : MonoBehaviour
{
    public SpinableObject[] objectsToRotate;
    private Rotate _rotate;
    private int index = 0;
    private bool rotateAll;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        var _objecttorotate = objectsToRotate[index];
        _rotate.t = _objecttorotate.t;
        _rotate.rotationSpeed = _objecttorotate.rotationSpeed;
        _rotate.minSpeed = _objecttorotate.minSpeed;
        _rotate.maxSpeed = _objecttorotate.maxSpeed;
        _rotate.speedRate = _objecttorotate.speedRate;
        _rotate.slowDown = _objecttorotate.slowDown;
        index++;
    }
}
```

And created a new script name Rotate:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Rotate : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform t;
    public float rotationSpeed;
    public float minSpeed;
    public float maxSpeed;
    public float speedRate;
    public bool slowDown;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start ()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update ()
    {
        RotateObject();
    }

    public void RotateObject()
    {
        if (rotationSpeed > maxSpeed)
            slowDown = true;
        else if (rotationSpeed < minSpeed)
            slowDown = false;

        rotationSpeed = (slowDown) ? rotationSpeed - 0.1f : rotationSpeed + 0.1f;
        t.Rotate(Vector3.forward, Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed);
    }
}
```

The idea is to feed the variables and settings in the script Rotate from the script SpinableObject.

But i messed it up it's not working and give me some null exception.

Is it a good way ? And how can i fix the scripts to work with each other so the SpinableObject will feed the Rotate with data.

Comment: So the objects have got a common property which they use when they rotate all at the same time, and then a particular property to rotate independently?

Comment: @IgnacioAlorre yes that's the idea. When the rotateAll is false use the property area for independently this part is working. And when rotateAll is true use a property area for all of them together.

Comment: Above I gave you how I would solve it. I usually prefer to add the scripts which performs the actions over a GameObject inside the GameObject itself. With this you can customise each GameObject easier from the inspector. Imagine they are planets, you can add a different spining speed from there

Comment: Where are you getting the null exception? In the array? The thing is you are trying to make each gameObject rotate from the same Script. It is an option, but I still think the approach I offered in my answer is easier. I would recommend you to watch some tutorials, if you havent yet, of the Unity web site (for example the survival game). You will see there they make simple scripts for almost anything, one for moving, one for shooting... And they attach this scripts directly to the gameObject, so can't be null exception. I will edit my answer as well

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would approach your problem.

I will define a global variable to determine if objects are rotating all at the same time or independently.

Then I will create a script called *rotation* and I will add it to each GameObject in your scene which will rotate.

In this script I will just include the

```
...
    Update()
    {
      if (rotateAll == false)
      {
        Rotate(allProperties)
      }else{
        Rotate(particularProperties)
      }
    }

    //Here you can implement the Rotate function passing the attributes you consider to make the rotation different for each case

...
```

And about global variables in Unity. One possible approach is to define a class like:

```
public static class GlobalVariables{
      public static boolean rotationType; 
 }
```

Then you can access and modigy this variable from another script like:

```
GlobalVariables.rotationType = true;

if(GlobalVariables.rotationType){
 ...
}
```

After Edit:

I can´t really tell what you are doing wrong, but if there is a null exception it may be you are not calling properly from the script the gameObjects you want to rotate. It could be you are not linking them correctly in the inspector. If you have declare

```
public SpinableObject[] objectsToRotate;
```

It is possible you forgot to drag and drop in the inspector the GamesObjets into the array to populate it. But I can't be sure if the problem is just that.